# Generating functions and Jacobi's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble proving this equality: $R(n) = \sigma(n/4) $ where $n/4$ is an odd positive integer or $R(n)=0$ in other case. $R(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of four odd squares.
Let also $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of the (positive) divisors of $n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
Also I do have the hint to use the following expressions
\begin{align*}
   F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)z^{2k+1}}{1-z^{4k+2}}\quad \text{and} \quad G(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{(2k+1)^2}
\end{align*}
with the relation between the two.
\begin{align*}
   F(z^4)=(G(z))^4.
\end{align*}

As far as my attempts have gone I could only reach the following expression

\begin{align*}
    F(z^4)=\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \frac{(n/4)z^n}{1-z^{2n}}\; \text{if $n$ is of the form}\; n=8k+4
\end{align*}
I am interested on an expression following this calculation depending on $R$.

Another problem is knowing how to power the sum $G(z)$ as needed, should I use the Cauchy product law? Am I missing an easier way of computing it?

I have also proved

\begin{align*}
   n=4\left[1+\sum_{i=1}^4 (k_i^2+k_i)\right],
\end{align*}
therefore, $n$ must be a multiple of 4.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to generating function, and not that hard. We want to use the relation \begin{align*}
   F(z^4)=(G(z))^4.
\end{align*}

It is easy to see that the coefficient of $z^n$ in $(G(z))^4$ is $R(n)$. We want to show that the coefficient of $z^n$ in $F(Z^4)$ is $\sigma(n/4)$.

\begin{align*}
   F(z^4)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+1)(z^4)^{2k+1}}{1-(z^4)^{4k+2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (2k+1)(z^4)^{(2k+1)*(2j+1)} 
\end{align*}

So the coefficient of $z^n$ in $F(z^4)$  is the sum of $2k+1$ for which there exists a $j$ such that $n=4(2k+1)(2j+1)$,  which is $\sigma(n/4).$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very clarifying. The last $\sigma(n) $  should be $\sigma(n/4)$, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks.          I will edit it